# WPF DataGrid Row add in codebehind

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, addition

I am from VB.Net WinForms comming. Now I wanted to write a small app in WPF, listing some files in a datagridview. I used WPF's DataGrid, created some Columns. And then failed to add my rows.

Please, can you help me to select the right way to get my filenames, state-text and thumbnails added to the DataGrid Row?

In VB.Net WinForms I can add a row like this:

```
Datagridview1.Rows.add(Myvalue, "RowStateText", "Hello World", MyDate)
```

In WPF's DataGrid I can add

```
DataGrid1.Items.Add(New DataGridRow())
```

But how to fill my DataGridRow?

```
  Private Sub AddFilesAndFolders(ByVal Base As IO.DirectoryInfo, ByRef dgv As DataGrid)
        'For Each di As IO.DirectoryInfo In Base.GetDirectories
        '    Call AddFilesAndFolders(di, dgv)
        'Next

        Dim item As DataGridRow



        For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In Base.GetFiles
            item = New DataGridRow'<-- test 1 (row is added but empty)
            Dim di As New MyFileInfo'<-- test 2 (my own class with public members, but how to add as row with declared columns?)
            di.FileName = fi.FullName
            di.FileDate = fi.LastAccessTime

            item.Item = fi.FullName
            dgv.Items.Add(di)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. Now I decided to add the current state of project as download:
http://www.goldengel.ch/temp/FileContent%20Replacer.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi: you should set an ItemsSource instead of adding items manually.  If the columns are set up correctly then it will just 'work'!

```
dbv.ItemsSource = Base.GetFiles
```

or

```
dbv.ItemsSource = CreateMyFileInfos(Base.GetFiles)
```

If you have any more problems, please post back here.

Edit: on second inspection it looks like you may want to be doing it recursively.  In which case your `AddFilesAndFolders` could instead be `CreateFilesAndFolders`, which would return a collection of FileInfo/MyFileInfo objects, merged with the collections produced by the child folders recursively; then bind the whole list returned from the first call, to the grid.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Kieren. I first tried your sample: dbv.ItemsSource = Base.GetFiles. But this already did not work. I you tell me, there could be a CreateMyFileInfos() function, how do the dgv know in what column to set the data? I cant use a List(Of MyClass), can I?

Comment: Have you set up the columns for your DataGridView in the XAML?  That tells the control what field to display in each column

Comment: This is my XAML. <DataGrid x:Name="dgv" Grid.Column="1">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Directory" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Filename" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Content" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Preview" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Done" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>

Comment: am I right to post here, or have I to click on "Answer" below?

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn(VS.95).aspx you need to specify a Binding for each column. That should fix it!

Comment: I tried it. It does ask me for another declaration. 
Can you see the project and tell me how to get the binding working?
http://www.goldengel.ch/temp/FileContent%20Replacer.zip

Answer (score 0):

WPF is a mindset change, you need to get away from the Winforms way of thinking.

Ultimately you need to set the ItemsSource to an IEnumerable, preferably a ObservableCollection.

The quickest way to get started would be to put the ObservableCollection as a public property in your code-behind file:

```
public ObservableCollection<DirectoryInfo> files { get;set; }
```

Then in the constructor or a Load event on the Window, populate the collection with your data and then add to the Xaml declaration for your DataGrid:

```
ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=files}"
```

EDIT:

I tried this out using the DirectoryInfo class, in my code behind I added:

```
    public ObservableCollection<DirectoryInfo> Dir = new ObservableCollection<DirectoryInfo>();
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dir.Add(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\"));
        Dir.Add(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp\\"));
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Dir;
    }
```

For some reason this was not working using the Databinding via Xaml, but I did not try very hard to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I am sure you are right, I have to remind me. Please, can you make a short example. Where have I to put the Ovservable Flag? And how to get individual Strings then (not only the DirectoryInfo).
public ObservableCollection<DirectoryInfo> files { get;set; }
?

Comment: In my XAML I have no ItemSource property to choose. Or where to set?

Comment: If the data in your own object used for the collection is changed during runtime, you should make it an ObservableObject and raise propertychange for each value inside it. The DataGrid will reflect these changes automatically then.

Comment: I cannot bind an Itemsource, because I always have a different amount of  columns