# How to bind to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

I tried to understand but failed. In WinForms I can build up some rows in a datagridview. By using Application.DoEvents (not nice but works) I can see how it is building up also when the list is very huge. I just want some similar in WPF.

Here is my project: 
http://www.goldengel.ch/temp/FileContent%20Replacer.zip

I already posted this question 
[WPF DataGrid Row add in codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262899/wpf-datagrid-row-add-in-codebehind)
but never was answered in time I need it (one week).
Please, can you send me the solution how it works in the project?

Would be great.

Nasenbaer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can find Microsoft sample very useful!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

And here is other one

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/620-using-the-wpf-net-40-datagrid-.html