# How to bind data collection to a DataGrid in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a small WPF application using MVVM design pattern. I want to create a CRUD like where I display the data in a `DataGrid`.

How do I bind each row in the `DataGrid` to my `Address` model?

Here is how my View-Model look like.

```
public class AddressViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    // .... stripped for simplicity.
}
```

Here is what I have in my view

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <Binding Path="Addresses" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zip Code" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="County" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to DataGrid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283271/how-to-bind-to-datagrid-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Binding` property of each column to a binding that binds to a *public property* of the `Address` class:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding City}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" Binding="{Binding State}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also make sure that you set the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`, or any its parent elements, to an instance of your view model class:

```
dg.DataContext = new AddressViewModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DataContext of your Datagrid to your collection

Name your datagrid in your XAML to help with the code behind like below:

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgAddresses">
```

So if you create the IEnumerable like so(I assume you are creating and populating that list in some other manner):

```
 var addressList = new IEnumerable<Address>();

 dgAddresses.DataContext = AddressList;
```